# RazorView Dropdown options generated by the textfields above MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razorengine

I am working on the register form.
I have a field DisplayName which needs to be populated by drop down options. Options in Drop Down list are the following:

- First Name only
- Last Name only
- First + Last Name
- Last + First Name
- Username

FirstName, LastName and email values are taken from the form. How can i get these values from the form in razorView? Also if some of the fields are empty there should not be any dropdown option... So dropdown is generating on go.

I am completely new to front-end development, I appreciate your help

My code of the current form (without the dropdown)

```
<div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen  animated fadeInDown">
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

Comment: you can achieve this by Jquery Ajax. You can write a code for the display name in the dropdown change event.

Comment: What is you `DisplayName` property - is it a `string` or `enum` to identify the possible values? You need to use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` t generate the `<select>` and bind to `DisplayName`, and then use javascritpt to hide/show the appropriate options based on the state of the other form controls

Comment: DisplayName property is a string, but as a combination of previously defined words

i.e: these are previously defined values:First name: Michael
      Last Name: Jordan
      username: micjord

The dropdown is supposed to be:
     - Michael
     - Jordan
     - Michael Jordan
     - Jordan Michael
     - micjord

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `enum` and use a helper method, like this:

```
@model HelperMethods.Models.Role

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(Model.GetType()), Model.ToString()))
```

In this case, I have created an `enum` called Role and populated my dropdownlist with the name of the elements in it.